# open with explorer disabled for external clients sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

We have shared some folders in our document library to external client and are available for them. But i am not sure how to enable the  open with explorer options to them.

Please advise.

Comment: Do they use Internet Explorer 32-bit version and are members of the site?

Comment: "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" - deactivate this feature from site collection features

Comment: what does it do ? .The option is available for us. only to the external clients who is not in our domain has this problem

Comment: yes IE is 32 bit

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3039997

When you share a folder with a user who can't access the parent folder or site, SharePoint assigns the user limited access to the parent items. Specifically, SharePoint lets the user access the folder without obtaining permission to access the parent folder and other items (other than limited access). However, after Limited-access user permission lockdown mode is enabled, the user doesn't have access to the folder because the necessary limited access permission on other items no longer works correctly.

Comment: oh thanks , just wondering with the users who has virus affected in their pc will it affect the sharepoint as well ?

Comment: dont think will affect SharePoint. Am adding extra comments in the answer section.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deactivate the `"Limited-access user permission lock down mode"` feature from the site collection.

Because this feature is activated by default, from [Users can't access a shared folder in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3039997) following happens:

> When you share a folder with a user who can't access the parent folder
>   or site, SharePoint assigns the user limited access to the parent
>   items. Specifically, SharePoint lets the user access the folder
>   without obtaining permission to access the parent folder and other
>   items (other than limited access). However, after Limited-access user
>   permission lockdown mode is enabled, the user doesn't have access to
>   the folder because the necessary limited access permission on other
>   items no longer works correctly.

Also, this kinda disables the open in explorer feature for users with limited access permission.

From [Enable or disable site collection features](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/confusion-with-enabledisable-limited-access-user/af0e43f7-228a-4032-9029-96945fc89c1a)

[image]

**Edit-**

You can try a couple of options as mentioned below:

1) Sign in to the SharePoint Online site by using your Office 365 work or school account credentials. When you do this, make sure that you select the Keep me signed in check box

2) Add the SharePoint online site to trusted sites.

You can try and follow this troubleshooting guide - [How to use the "Open with Explorer" command to troubleshoot issues in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2629108)

Comment: HI Gautham, this feature is not activated in the site collection level, still having problems to share folders to the third party